# change jquery-steps Previous button colour

Tags: jquery, jquery-steps

I have included the jquery-steps plugin. How can I change the colour of the Previous button without changing the next & finish button?

Thanks

http://www.jquery-steps.com/

[Previous button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZDuh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code for the button is the same like on the jquery-steps pages, you can access the styles by the href-attribute of the button like this:

```
a[href="#previous"] {
   background-color: red !important;
}
```

Note that setting `!important` to the value might not be necessary for you when you load your styles after the css needed for jquery steps, but it just was when I added the style using the DOM inspector.

Comment: To follow up on the answer by matthias_h.  The CSS Rule of Specificity (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) is why !important was needed in his answer.  If the selector contains "selector types" then !important would not be needed.  For example use the following with more selector arguments,  ".wizard > .actions a[href="#previous"] {
    background-color: red;
}"